# Oracle proxy user in vb

Tags: oracle, vb.net, oracle11g, oracle10g

I use a vb application that connect to an Oracle service by an Oracle client 10g:

```
Protected cnS3 As OracleConnection
cnS3 = New OracleConnection(String.Format("Data Source={0};user id={1}; password={2}; ", _
                              "myDataSource10", "dbUser", "dbUserPassword"))
```

But the db provider has dismissed the Oracle user and has provided me a proxy user. It told me to connect with the proxy user and Oracle client 11.2.0.4.
So I've installed the Oracle client 11g and created a new ODBC DSN "myDataSource11" with Oracle 11g version (tested and worked in the ODBC Data Sources Interface).
But when replace the code as follows:

```
Protected cnS3 As OracleConnection
cnS3 = New OracleConnection(String.Format("Data Source={0};user id={1}; password={2}; ", _
                              "myDataSource11", "dbProxyUser[dbUser]", "dbProxyUserPassword"))
```

I have the error: ***[OracleException (0x80131938): ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified***
I have also tried with this code:

```
oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (LOAD_BALANCE = ON) (FAILOVER = ON)" _ 
    + "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=myhostname)(PORT=5555))" _ 
    + "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=myhostname2)(PORT=5555)))(CONNECT_DATA" _ 
    + "= (SERVICE_NAME = myServiceName )));" _
    + "User Id=dbProxyUser[dbUser];Password=dbProxyUserPassword;"
cnS3 = New OracleConnection(oradb)
```

And in this case the error is ***[ArgumentException: Lunghezza dell'opzione di connessione "user id" non valida. La lunghezza massima è 30.]***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved replacing the OracleConnection with OdbcConnection.
The proxy user has been added also in the web.config and the password of the proxy user has been added in the odbc, as explained at https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2209660/ora-01005-null-password-given-error-on-windows-7